# Convert a column of data in Excel into proper date time format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have data with several columns of date time info that is formatted like this: 2014-03-01 00:33:11 UTC

Excel doesn't recognize it as valid date data. Is there any way to convert the data in place (I don't want to add columns) so that I can use the data as an Excel date time value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the cells and do a Find and Replace to delete the " UTC" from the end of each date time.

[image: Excel Find and Replace]

Excel should then correctly parse the date time.

Comment: So obvious that I feel totally foolish for not thinking of it! Thanks.